# FreeBCP to SQL Azure complains table doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, freetds, freebcp

```
$ freebcp DWSTAGE.BCPTEST in bcptest.txt -f cdr.fmt -S serverfromfreetds -U user@azureserver -P password
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1
Server 'azureserver', Line 1
    Invalid object name 'DWSTAGE.BCPTEST'.
Msg 208, Level 16
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server

Msg 20064, Level 2
Attempt to use Bulk Copy with a non-existent Server table

$ freebcp DATABASENAME.DWSTAGE.BCPTEST in bcptest.txt -f cdr.fmt -S serverfromfreetds -U user@azureserver -P password
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1
Server 'azureserver', Line 16
    Reference to database and/or server name in 'DATABASENAME.DWSTAGE.BCPTEST' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Msg 40515, Level 15
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server

Msg 20064, Level 2
Attempt to use Bulk Copy with a non-existent Server table
```

I've also tried adding the database to the command line with the -D option.  The default database for that connection is set up as this one and only Azure database in the freetds.conf.

The connection to SQL Azure seems fine otherwise - I just can't get FreeBCP to work:

```
$ isql serverfromfreetds user@azuredatabasename password
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DWSTAGE.BCPTEST;
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
| 0          |
+------------+
SQLRowCount returns 1
1 rows fetched
SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DWSTAGE.BCPTESTX;
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute
SQL>
```

This seems like some database/schema confusion, but I can't find a combination of settings which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the FreeTDS mailing list:

The message 208 comes from the server.  A quick look at freebcp.c shows
argv[1] isn't parsed.  It's copied to a struct and used verbatim e.g.

```
                    if (dbfcmd(dbproc, "SET FMTONLY ON select *
```

from %s SET FMTONLY OFF", pdata->dbobject) == FAIL)

My guess is that the account you're logging in with has a default
database, and that database is not the one containing DWSTAGE.BCPTEST.
The Azure server rejects dbname.schema.object syntax, and freebcp has
no -D option because until Azure every TDS server did accept that
syntax.

You could verify that using

```
    $ freebcp 'select db_name()' queryout /dev/stdout ...
```

As a temporary workaround, I think this would work:

```
    freebcp DWSTAGE.BCPTEST in bcptest.txt \
    -O 'USE dbname' \
    -f cdr.fmt -S serverfromfreetds -U user@azureserver -P password
```

A permanent fix would support -D.

---

Yes, that user's default database is probably master.  There IS a
default database set up in the odbc config, but I was mistaken, there
is no such option in the freeetds.conf.

We've moved away from trying to get Linux to work for this process for
now, but I'll revisit this.

I expect that workaround will not work because USE isn't supported -
you do in fact have to connect directly to the database, because of
the nature of the SQL Azure architecture.

---

Yes, you're right. I forgot about that.

About a year ago we added the DBSETLDBNAME macro as a way to set the
dbname in the db-lib LOGINREC.  That sets the dbname in the login
packet, obviating the need for "USE dbname".  freebcp could be modified
to support that feature with a -D option.

---

See change

http://gitorious.org/freetds/freetds/commit/4a21ded022405693607e71938d0c6173816f5ff9/diffs/c34afafd2fec4cbba9b245e4f13a5471c6fb8041

(add support for -D in freebcp)

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten `freebcp` working with Ubuntu 12.04 and Azure SQL.  It follows on to the answer above where support for `-D` is mentioned.

First I started by installing and configuring `freetds` as described in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/167491/connecting-ms-sql-using-freetds-and-unixodbc-isql-no-default-driver-specified

Basically, that consisted of:
`sudo apt-get install tdsodbc unixodbc freetds-bin`

That brought me to the point where this thread starts; `freebcp` could connect but I was getting the error about "Reference to database...not supported in this version of SQL server".

The next step is to note that the version of `freebcp` installed by apt-get is a quite old version.  Instead download a more recent version from ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/.  I used `freetds-1.00.9.tar.gz`.

Install it using `./configure` and `make` then use this new `freebcp` just the same but with `-D`.

Here is my command string: `freetds-1.00/src/apps/freebcp bcptest in bcptest.big.dat -U myUserName@myServer -S MyServerConfig -P 'mypa$$word' -D myDatabase -c -e upload.err`